# XPages XSP.partialRefreshGet strange effect on view container control

Tags: xpages

My theme is OneUI2 ...

On my XPage I have a VDS (view data source) and when links are clicked the associated document is loaded into a DDS below. I have a save button with 'No Update' set and the button event handler doing a partial refresh on the DDS and onComplete it does a partial refresh in the VDS. All works great, but something is happening to the view.

View Source shows the view inside a TABLE tag and after the partialRefreshGet on the VDS the table tag gets duplicated inside that 1st TABLE tag, so now I have a TABLE tag inside another TABLE tag (I'm ignoring the TR and TR tags here) and so on after each save of the VDS.

If I change the button to do a partial refresh of my VDS and the event handler to do a partial refresh of the DDS it works! But any CSJS doing a partial refresh of a VDS goes wrong.

Why is this happening and how can I stop this?
Has anyone done a partialRefreshGet on a VDS and got it to work without table tag getting added after each save?

Comment: Try to use another container for refresh just above view, for example xp:div or xp:panel.

Comment: Thought I had tried that, but tried it again after your suggestion and it work great! No idea what I did before. Thanks Frantisek.

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?

Comment: This user apparently never accepts answers anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you can try to continue using CSJS to perform partial refreshes:

- Make sure the Syntax of your XSP.partialRefreshGet is correct. **Note** the second argument of **{}** if you are not performing indented partial refreshes.

Syntax:

```
    XSP.partialRefreshGet(yourId, {});
```

- Try XSP.partialRefreshPost as a possible alternative. I sometimes have to jump between the 2 to get the results I'm looking for.

  ```
  XSP.partialRefreshPost(yourId, {});
  ```

Comment: The second parameter is only required for 8.5.3. The bug was fixed with ND9.